# ERC20 Token convert unit256 format depending on decimal

Tags: erc-20, decimals

Hello i am trying to convert unit256 format depending on the decimal value of each token address.

Decimal 9 and 18 ı did converted. they work fine as seen in the code below

but I don't know what to do for decimal 8 and 4. Can you help me with this?

```
exports.gweiToEth = (val, dec) => {
if (dec === "9") {
    return converter.convert(val, "gwei", "ether")
}
else if (dec === "18") {
    return converter.convert(val, "wei", "ether")
}
return val }
```

I would appreciate it if you share it by updating my code, thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use web3's conversion functions `fromWei` and `toWei`.

```
$ npm install web3



var Web3 = require('web3');
console.log(Web3.version);
// => 1.0.0-beta.34

const weiValue = Web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether');
console.log(weiValue);
// => 1000000000000000000

const etherValue = Web3.utils.fromWei('1000000000000000000', 'ether');
console.log(etherValue);
// => 1
```

An alternative is to just understand how it works mathematically and make your own function.  Refer to the links below.

**References:**

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html

https://medium.com/@piyopiyo/how-to-convert-ether-from-wei-and-vice-versa-with-web3-1-0-0-3e3e691e3f0e